# ¿Se puede cambiar el contenido de un contenedor a otro?

Tags: html5, flexbox

Quisera saber si se puedo cambiar el contenido de uno contenedor a otro cuando la página se hace responsive.
Quiero que en el siguiente ejemplo que coloco el contenido del aside quede en medio del artículo dos y tres

```
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo"></div>
  </div>
  <section class="section">
    <nav class="nav">
      <a href="">uno</a>
      <a href="">dos</a>
      <a href="">tres</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="articulos">
      <div class="articulo1"></div>
      <div class="articulo2"></div>
      <div class="articulo3"></div>
    </div>
    <aside class="aside">
      <div class="otro"></div>
      <div class="otro"></div>
    </aside>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Lucas, ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: soy nuevo. intente con order y no pude: buscando vi que se puede hacer por jquery pero tampoco funciono o bien lo hice mal

Comment: @LucasA. Sería bueno que mostraras el CSS con el que has probado. Así, te podríamos corregir los errores acordes a lo que has intentado y seguro que aprenderías mucho más :)

Answer (score 0):

creo que algo así es lo que buscas: https://codepen.io/zeross/pen/rdzOOE

Te explico un poco. He utilizado [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) de css para ordenar las distintas capas y [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries) para reubicarlas según el tamaño de la pantalla.

Si te fijas en el ejemplo, le aplico la propiedad **display:flex** a la capa padre para indicarle que debe comportarse como flexbox, a demás de la propiedad **flex-direction:column** para que las capas hijas se alineen verticalmente. Luego, a cada capa hijo le añado el atributo **order** con el orden deseado.

```
.section { display:flex; flex-direction:column; }

.nav { border:solid 1px red; order:1; }
.articulos { border:solid 1px blue; order:2; }
.aside { border:solid 1px green; order:3; }
```

Por último, utilizo la media query para decirles a las clases 'articulos' y 'aside' que inviertan su orden cuando la pantalla sea menor a 600px.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .articulos { order:3; }
  .aside { order:2; }
}
```

**Edit:**

Si lo que quieres es que sólo el artículo 3 se mueva, puedes sacar los elementos 'articulo1', 'articulo2' y 'articulo3' fuera de la clase 'articulo'. Luego tratas los órdenes independientes, en lugar de agrupados.

```css
.section { display:flex; flex-direction:column; }

.nav { border:solid 1px red; order:1; }
.articulo1 { border:solid 1px blue; order:2; }
.articulo2 { border:solid 1px yellow; order:3 }
.articulo3 { border:solid 1px black; order:4 }
.aside { border:solid 1px green; order:5; }

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .articulo3 { order:5; }
  .aside { order:4; }
}
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
   <div class="contenedor">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="logo"></div>
      </div>
      <section class="section">
        <nav class="nav">
          <a href="">uno</a>
          <a href="">dos</a>
          <a href="">tres</a>
        </nav>
        <div class="articulo1">art1</div>
        <div class="articulo2">art2</div>
        <div class="articulo3">art3</div>
        <aside class="aside">
          <div class="otro">otro1</div>
          <div class="otro">otro2</div>
        </aside>
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hola gracias por responder. lo hice asi. pero llo que yo quiero hacer es que el articulo3 quede por debajo de asidel

Comment: Respuesta editada.